# The History of .NET

Tags: .net, clr

I read some where that the .net runtime was effectively Visual Basic 6 (albeit completely re-written)

How true is this? or is this just another .NET myth?

Darknight

Comment: Where are you guys coming up with this stuff?  Yesterday it was "does C# perform better than VB.NET", now it is "isn't .NET just VB6++"?  What next "isn't C# just the love child of VB6 and C++"?

Comment: C# _is_ faster than VB.Net, surely. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It´s a Myth. You can read more about .Net Framework in the Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

The main difference is that VB is a language while .Net is a framework.

Answer (score 2):

Another .NET Myth

Answer (score 2):

.NET is both a mix of Visual Basic's Rapid Application Development influence, along with strong influence of very structured and unmanaged Object-Oriented languages (C, C++).

It abstracts away a lot from both worlds.

Some might argue it's a rewrite from Java ;)

Answer (score 0):

Surely VB6 has influenced .net.  Though I wouldn't call it a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that .Net is more of a descendant of Delphi than anything

Comment: No, Delphi is a programming language while .NET is a platform. But C# is mostly based on C++, Pascal (Delphi) and Java.

Comment: The .NET Framework was heavily inspired by Borland's VCL (not Delphi exactly, as the VCL was used by C++Builder as well) ... however, .NET goes far beyond what the VCL ever was.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost .net is a Virtual Machine and a Framework surrounding that VM. C#, VB and F# for example compile down to IL (intermediate language) that can be interpreted by the VM. This way some (for example) clever tricks can be done in the space of memory management, application security and portability.

One example of such a feature is the garbage collector.